# Is it possible to create an text box (InputText) in pysimplegui that auto completes the thing the user is trying to enter?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I was wondering if there was some type of Parameter that a pysimplegui text box takes that allows it to auto complete the thing the user is trying to enter. This might sound confusing so let me give an example. Lets say you make an Input Text and above it it says "Whats your favourite fruit?", as the user starts to type "apple" (for example"), all fruits (that you have predefined beforehand in a list or some other way) that start with "a" come up, then all fruits with "ap" and so on. The user can then somehow select the fruit they were trying to type. Does this thing exist in pysimplegui or tkinter? Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't exist in `tkinter`, although you could implement it yourself using the facilities it does provide.

Comment: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Input_Auto_Complete.py